# How to simulate and submit a form in Go with SalesForce webtolead?

Tags: go, salesforce

The [Salesforce webtolead feature](https://www.shellblack.com/marketing/web-to-lead/) is an html form that can be embedded on a web page and is submitted using a url in the form action.

I'm aware that you can take information from a form in HTML and perform functions in Go with that information. However what I'm trying to figure out is if it's possible to simulate the creation of an HTML form in the backend with Go and POST to the Salesforce url in the form action.

The reason for this is because the creation of this form and subsequent submission is interfering with some tracking functionality from the redirects.

I'm essentially trying to remove the form submission from the frontend completely and only use it to send the necessary field information to the backend from where I'll create and submit the form itself.

Is something like this possible?

I have looked into various libraries like "html/template" and "net/http" but from understanding these only deal with the handling of form submissions from the front end. They don't appear to create and submit data from the Backend independent of the frontend which is what I'm hoping to accomplish.

Comment: *"However what I'm trying to figure out is if it's possible to simulate the creation of an HTML form in the backend with Go and POST to the Salesforce url in the form action. ... Is something like this possible?"* -- Yes, it's possible. See [`net/http.PostForm`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.17.8#PostForm). Note that, as documented, PostForm sends a POST request with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content, which is equivalent to submitting an HTML form with method=POST.

Comment: Perfect thank you I think this is exactly what I was looking for.